# How to display different data based on radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, event-listener

I'm new to Javascript /HTML/CSS and am struggling to display different data based on radio button selection. I want to run a different query to my database based on whether radio button 1 or 2 is selected, and i don't know what methods i can use to do so. How do i store and use the information that a certain radio button has been selected.

In my Javascript file:

```
`html = html + """
            <p id='dataTitle'>Global population and average temperature for:</p>
            <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input type="radio" id="option1" name="radioOptions" value="option1">
            <label for="option1">1750</label>

            <input type="radio" id="option2" name="radioOptions" value="option2">
            <label for="option2">2013</label>
            </div>


            """; `
```

In my CSS file:

```
`.radio-label {
display: block;
margin-top: 300px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.radio-label input\[type="radio"\] {
display: none;
}

.radio-label input\[type="radio"\] + label:before {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
margin-right: 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 50%;
font-size: 32px;
}

.radio-label input\[type="radio"\]:checked + label:before {
background-color: #e3a541;
}

.radio-wrapper {
display: flex;
padding-top: 40px;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
}

.radio-wrapper input\[type="radio"\] {
display: none;
}

.radio-wrapper label {
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 120px;
height: 80px;
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: #D88B1F;
border: 1px solid #050404;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.radio-wrapper input\[type="radio"\]\[value="option2"\] + label {
border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; /\* Rounded right corners for Option 2 \*/
}

.radio-wrapper input\[type="radio"\]:checked + label {
background-color: #A86E1E;
color: black;
}`
```

I've tried implementing event listeners unsuccessfully.

Comment: I assume you mean javascript and not java, they are entirely different. Tags and text corrected.